# Requirement, design, code derivation

Tags: documentation, verification

I am following verification and validation threads and I think an example might be helpful. I am not an experienced developer so I would like to know whether this would be correct:

1. User equirement: I want to be save my friend's name, address and phone number to the system
2. Software Requirement specification: User wants to be able to enter and save a name, address, phone number.
3. Technical analysis: web UI for data entering. Data will be saved into the SQL DB.
4. Detailed design: UI elements: 3 fields of a string type, 1 button, object XYZ, dbConnection....
5. Code: (actual code of UI, db scripts)

**Is it like that? Could anyone correct or add what I am missing here?**

As for verification, each phase can be verified against requirement (traceability). As for validation, the functional code should work as expected (save three attributes).

Comment: I think the general idea is correct, but it should be as specific as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is some what theoretically true (I have to say this), it is completely wrong in all practical and real world scenarios.

Capture user needs and **Why** he wants to do a certain thing. This allows you to build just the software that user wants, eliminate waste that come as part of made-up requirements, technical requirements, nice to haves etc.

So instead of,

```
I want to be save my friend's name, address and phone number to the system...
```

I'd rather like to have the below which emphasizes **Why?** the **real need** of the user

> I want to send a greeting card to my friend on his birthday.

Now, I know I just need his name and address. Since this is for future I also want to store this information. So what I write next is a set of acceptance criteria to meet the above customer needs. If I can capture these as a set of executable specifications then it is even better as those are *verifiable* programmatically.

Ignore everything else. Traceability is unnecessary overhead. We need it if we are building software based on fabricated requirements.

Read the below

- [Agile Manifesto](http://agilemanifesto.org/)
- [ATDD](http://testobsessed.com/2008/12/acceptance-test-driven-development-atdd-an-overview/) and [BDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development)
- [Impact Mapping](http://www.impactmapping.org/index.php)

Comment: +1: "Traceability is unnecessary overhead.". And I would add BDD to your list.

Comment: Once some one searches for atdd or executable requirements then DVD will definately show up. I didn't want the post to overload with buzz words so...

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen a good way to trace code to requirements outside a single sprint/time box. And also, you're missing testers from your list! Unless your testers are also your business analysts (I my experience professional testers find a lot of the requirements inconsistencies - aka bugs).

I think the best approach is to have everyone as involved as possible, so you can cross reference each person expectations often. If everyone works together, you don't need to implement a cargo-cult process where batches of information are transferred down stream in one way.

The simplest tool have traceability is your VCS, where each commit includes the ID of the user story/use case that the commit is related to.

Comment: Well testers are involved in the validation, once the code is executable. Verification is rarely done by testers, rather than analyst, developers (static analysis)

Comment: Hi Terry, I strongly disagree with what you said. I testers can contribute a lot to the verification of requirements to stop, among other things: gaps in requirements, requirements that contradict each other in subtle ways, find UI usability flaws before they are implemented. Obviously, this depends on the type of testers you hire. Professional testers Vs. people who can use the mouse, keyboard and read a test script. If you want to investigate this a bit more, I suggest you to read the book [Agile Testing](http://www.bookdepository.co.uk/Agile-Testing-Lisa-Crispin/9780321534460)